# draggable text box on top of canvas image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

hello everyone so I am trying to make a draggable text box in canvas. But when I cant seem to figure out the functionality. All I want to do is drag the text box around on top of the image. It would be really cool to just be able to click and drag the text around. Does anybody know how to do this? its becoming a headache. if you have any suggestions that'd be great.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <canvas id="canvas" width='500' height='500' ref='canvas' @mousedown='handleMouseDown' @mouseout='resetSelectedText' @mouseup='resetSelectedText' @mousemove='handleMouseMove'></canvas>
   <input v-model="text" placeholder='type your text'>
   <button @click='addText'>
   add text
   </button>
   <div v-for="(text, index) in texts">
   {{text.text}} <div @click='removeText(index)'>X</div>
   </div>
   <img src ='https://shop-resources.prod.cms.tractorsupply.com/resource/image/18248/portrait_ratio3x4/595/793/4c37b7f6d6f9d8a5b223334f1390191b/JJ/ten-reasons-not-to-buy-an-easter-bunny-main.jpg' @click="changeBackground('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv')">
   <img src ='https://ce.prismview.com/api/files/templates/43s327k3oqfsf7/poster/poster.jpg' @click="changeBackground('http://ce.prismview.com/api/files/templates/43s327k3oqfsf7/main/360/43s327k3oqfsf7_360.mp4')">

    <video id="video" ref='video' :src="source" controls="false" autoplay loop></video>

    </div>
<script>
        new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data: {
                source: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv",
                canvas: null,
                ctx: null,
                video: null,
                text:'',
                timer: null,
                texts: [],
                selectedText: null,
                startX: null,
                startY: null
              },
                methods: {
                addText(){
                if(this.text.length){
                let textObj = {
                text: this.text,
                x: 20,
                y: this.texts.length * 20 + 20
                };
                this.texts.push(textObj);
                this.text = '';
                }
                },
                removeText(i){
                this.texts.splice(i);
                },
                textInRange(x, y, textIndex){
                let t = this.texts[textIndex];
                 return (x >= t.x && x <= t.x + t.width && y >= t.y - t.height && y <= t.y);
                },
                handleMouseDown(e){
                console.log('yes', e.offsetX);
                this.startX = parseInt(e.clientX - 20);
                this.startY = parseInt(e.clientY - 20);
                for(let i =0; i<this.texts.length; i++){
                if(this.textInRange(this.startX, this.startY, i)){
                this.selectedText = i;
                console.log(this.selectedText);
                } else { console.log('not in range');}
                }
                },
                resetSelectedText(e){
                this.selectedText = -1;
                },
                handleMouseMove(e){
                if(this.selectedText <0){
                return;
                }
                let mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - e.offsetX);
                let mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - e.offsetY);
                let dx = mouseX - this.startX;
                let dy = mouseY - this.startY;
                if(this.selectedText!=null){
                let t = this.texts[this.selectedText];
                t.x += dx;
                t.y = dy;
                }
                },
                    drawFrame (){
                        console.log("drawing");
                          this.ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0,);
                          this.ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                          this.ctx.font = "30px Arial";
                          for(let i =0; i<this.texts.length; i++){
                                                    this.ctx.fillText(this.texts[i].text, this.texts[i].x, this.texts[i].y);
                          }
                       this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                       this.drawFrame()
                       }, 1000/30);

                      },

              initCanvas(){
                this.canvas = this.$refs['canvas'];
                this.video = this.$refs['video'];
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
               const vm = this;
               this.video.addEventListener('play', function(){
               vm.video.style.display = 'none';

               vm.drawFrame();
               })
              },
              changeBackground(source){
              if(source!=this.video.src){
              clearTimeout(this.timer);
              this.source = source;
              this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
              this.ctx.restore();
              }
              }
        },
        mounted: function(){
            this.initCanvas();
        }
      });

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Dragging canvas content.

Use `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `mousemove` event listeners just to update the mouse state. Eg the position and the button state.

The logic to drag rendered items should be done in the main render loop. In the example `renderLoop` calls `handleMouse` before rendering any content.

Rather than do a full VUE app example I have done the most basic text drag and drop so you can see a code example.

### Drag start and drag move

In `handleMouse` check if mouse is down `mouse.button === true`

- if so and not dragging and there is text to drag under the mouse set dragging to true  and calculate the offset from the mouse pos to the text `x`, `y`
- "Drag" if the mouse is down and dragging true then update the selected text position by setting it to the mouse position plus the drag offset

### Drag drop

If the mouse is up `mouse.button === false`

- and dragging is true then set `dragging` to false. The selected text item is dropped
- set `selectedText` to the first text item under the mouse.

### Render loop

Also handles highlighting and cursors for the mouse and text to give positive feedback to the user.

### Text Items

I have extended an array to handle text items. The important function is much the same as you had `textItems.getUnder(point)` return the text item under `point.x` `point.y`. If the point is not over a text item then the function returns `undefined`.

### Example

As an example it may not meet all your needs, and is by no means the only way to handle drag and drop for rendered canvas content.

I hope this helps.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);          
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var selectedText;
const mouse = {
    x: 0, 
    y: 0,
    bounds: canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    button: false,
    dragging: false,
    dragOffsetX: 0,
    dragOffsetY: 0,
    events(event) {  // mouse event handler should only record current mouse state
        const m = mouse;
        if (event.type === "mousedown") { m.button = true }
        else if (event.type === "mouseup") { m.button = false }
        m.x = event.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
        m.y = event.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
    }   
};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse.events);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouse.events);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouse.events);
function renderLoop(time) {
    if (!textItems.length) { addDemoText() }
    textItems[0].update("Frame time: " + time.toFixed(3) + "ms");
    var cursor = "default";
    handleMouse();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    textItems.draw(ctx);
    if (selectedText) { 
        cursor = mouse.dragging ? "none" : "move";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#08F"; // highlight selected text
        selectedText.draw();
    }
    canvas.style.cursor = cursor;
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop); 
}
function handleMouse() {
    const m = mouse;
    const text = selectedText;
    if (m.button) {
        if (!m.dragging && text !== undefined) {
            m.dragging = true;
            m.dragOffsetX = text.x - m.x;
            m.dragOffsetY = text.y - m.y;
        }
        if (m.dragging) {
            text.x = m.x + m.dragOffsetX;
            text.y = m.y + m.dragOffsetY;
            text.keepOnCanvas()
        }
    } else {
        if (m.dragging) {                 
            selectedText = undefined;
            m.dragging = false;
        }
        selectedText = textItems.getUnder(m);
    }
}

const textItems = Object.assign([],{
    getUnder(point) { // returns undefined if no text under
        for(const t of this) {
            if (point.x >= t.x && point.x <= t.x + t.width && point.y < t.y + t.size && point.y >= t.y) {
                return t;
            }
        }
    },
    add(ctx, text, x,  y, color = "#000", size = 24, font = "arial") { // context ctx to measure the text
        var item;
        ctx.font = size + "px " + font;
        const width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
        this.push(item = {text, x, y, color, font, size, width,
            draw() { 
                ctx.font = this.size + "px " + this.font;
                ctx.textBaseline = "hanging";
                ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
            },
            keepOnCanvas() {
                const maxX = ctx.canvas.width - this.width;
                const maxY = ctx.canvas.height - this.size;
                this.x < 0 && (this.x = 0);
                this.y < 0 && (this.y = 0);
                this.x >= maxX && (this.x = maxX - 1);
                this.y >= maxY && (this.y = maxY - 1);
            }, 
            update(text) {
                this.text = text;
                ctx.font = this.size + "px " + this.font;
                this.width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
                this.keepOnCanvas();
            }
        });
        return item;
    },
    draw(ctx) {
        for(const text of this) {
            ctx.fillStyle = text.color;
            text.draw();
        }
    }
});
function addDemoText() { 
    var idx = 0;
    textItems.add(ctx, "", 0, 0);
    for (const t of "HI there! Some text to move with the mouse. Move mouse  over text items. Click and drag to move the text.  ".split(" ")) {
        const text = textItems.add(ctx, t, idx % (canvas.width - 80), (idx / (canvas.width - 80) | 0) * 26 + 26);
        text.keepOnCanvas();
        idx += text.width + 12
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="180">
```

Comment: Really impressive